# Spring Security Active Directory LDAP Authentication without full name

Tags: java, spring-security, active-directory, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

Using Spring Security 3.2  I have configured ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. I am able to authenticate using full name  example sharon@mydomain.com but when I try to authenticate with just username 'sharon'  I get the below error

```
   2015-12-21_17:07:00.752 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.a.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - authenticate - Processing authentication request for user: sharon
    2015-12-21_17:07:00.793 DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - searchForSingleEntryInternal - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=mydomain,dc=com', filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))'
    2015-12-21_17:07:00.793 INFO  o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - searchForSingleEntryInternal - Ignoring PartialResultException
    2015-12-21_17:07:00.794 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider - authenticate - Processing authentication request for user: gdcadmin
    2015-12-21_17:07:00.796 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - bindWithDn - Attempting to bind as cn=gdcadmin,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=springframework,dc=org
    2015-12-21_17:07:00.796 DEBUG o.s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource - setupEnvironment - Removing pooling flag for user cn=gdcadmin,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=springframework,dc=org
    2015-12-21_17:07:00.858 DEBUG o.a.m.f.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter - messageReceived - Processing a MESSAGE_RECEIVED for session 1
    2015-12-21_17:07:00.859 DEBUG o.a.d.shared.asn1.ber.Asn1Decoder - decode - >>>==========================================
.....
.....
.....
015-12-21_17:07:00.905 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - handleBindException - Failed to bind as cn=gdcadmin,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn.]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn.]
```

As per spring security document :

> A user named "Sharon", for example, would then be able to authenticate
>   by entering either the username sharon or the full Active Directory
>   userPrincipalName, namely sharon@mydomain.com

my configuration

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("cn={0},CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com");
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(env.getProperty("mydomain.com"),
                env.getProperty("ldap://hmidir01.mydomain.com:389/"));
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);
        return provider;
    }
```

What is the mistake in my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> You can implement in given ways **:**

**1) Without persisting data into our database**

> WebSecurityConfig .java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(<ldap-domain>,<ldap-url>);
            provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
            provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggerListener loggerListener() {
        return new LoggerListener();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/rest/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error").successHandler("/home").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("emailId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/home")
        .and()
            .csrf()
        .and()
            .httpBasic();    
    }
}
```

**2) With persisting data into our database**

> WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/rest/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error").successHandler("/home").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("emailId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/home")
        .and()
            .csrf()
        .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)throws Exception {
        auth
    .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(<ldap-domain>(null), <ldap-url>);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new AttributesLDAPUserDetailsContextMapper();
    }
}
```

> AttributesLDAPUserDetailsContextMapper.java

```
    public class AttributesLDAPUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {


        @Autowired
        private UserService service;

        private InetOrgPersonContextMapper ldapUserDetailsMapper = new InetOrgPersonContextMapper();

        @Override
        public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations dirContextOperations, String userName, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {

            InetOrgPerson userLdap = (InetOrgPerson) ldapUserDetailsMapper.mapUserFromContext(dirContextOperations, userName, collection);  

            User user = service.findOne(userLdap.getUsername());
            if (user == null) {
                user = new Usere();
                user.setName(StringUtils.defaultString(userLdap.getDisplayName()).trim());
                user.setEmailId(StringUtils.defaultString(userLdap.getUsername()).trim());
                user.setdescription(StringUtils.defaultString(userLdap.getDescription()).trim());
                user.setIsAdmin(false);
                user.setIsEmployee(true);
                service.save(user);
            }
            return new LdapSecuredUser(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails userDetails, DirContextAdapter dirContextAdapter) {
            ldapUserDetailsMapper.mapUserToContext(userDetails, dirContextAdapter);
        }
    }
```

> LdapSecuredUser.java

```
public class LdapSecuredUser extends User implements LdapUserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8997460180274787521L;

    public LdapSecuredUser(User user) {
        if (user != null) {
            this.setId(user.getId());
            this.setEmailId(user.getEmailId());
            this.setName(user.getName());
            this.setdescription(user.getDescription());
            this.setIsAdmin(user.getIsAdmin());
            this.setIsEmployee(user.getIsEmployee());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(); 
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        if(super.getIsAdmin())
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));   
        return authorities;
    }


    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getEmailId();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDn() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain. I fail to see the difference between your code and mine. My requirement is to authenticate with user name and not email /  full user name.

Answer (score 0):

With spring security 5.2.1:
You can use the `setSearchFilter()` function.

The LDAP auth process has two main steps: binding, which uses the domain parameter (the first) from `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()`to form the username like this: myUser@sub.domain.com
given credentials: username= myUser; password myPassword.
If this is is not correct, you'll get bad credential error (AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e).

Then the next step is to finding your user in the ldap directory.
If your user doesn't have an attribute named username which is = myUser@sub.domain.com, the ldap server will give you back a not found error (this will pop up in your log as `Ignoring PartialResultException` from an `UsernameNotFoundException: User myUser not found in directory.` exception. For this you can use the searchFilter option.
The provided username will be inserted at the `{1}` point.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic(); //this will invoke an auth popup in browser
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
       ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new 
       ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("sub.domain.com","ldap://url");
       provider.setSearchFilter("mailNickname={1}"); //here is the trick
       provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
       provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    return provider;
    }
}
```